How to make UWP MediaElement to be loop mode when casting to a TV?
I find that when using UWP MediaElement (component name: video), it works well to be in loop mode when set as below:
video.IsLooping = true;  // method 1
video.MediaEnded -= Video_MediaEnded;
video.MediaEnded += Video_MediaEnded;  // method 2

private void Video_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    video.Position = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
    video.Play();
}

But when casting the source to a smart TV (DLNA), then the loop mode doesn't work at all.
private CastingConnection connection;  

//Create a new casting connection to the device that's been selected
connection = (CastingDevice)castingDevicesList.SelectedItem).CreateCastingConnection();

//Register for events
connection.ErrorOccurred += Connection_ErrorOccurred;
connection.StateChanged += Connection_StateChanged;

//Cast the loaded video to the selected casting device.
CastingConnectionErrorStatus status = await connection.RequestStartCastingAsync(video?.GetAsCastingSource());

I add a timer to set the video.Position after a period of time, e.g. 10s, but has no impact at all.
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    if (video.Position >= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
    {
        video.Position = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
    }
}

Any advise?
I put my demo code here: https://github.com/tomxue/BasicMediaCasting/tree/develop   branch: develop
Anyone could take a try.
